# Javascript - only allow numbers in input field & a character counter

Tags: javascript

I have an input field. I want it so that only *numbers* can be used in the input field.

Below the input field I also want a counter that shows the number of characters currently inside the input field.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
<p id='demo'></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('test').value;
    let inputLength = inputValue.length;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputLength;
    return true;
    }
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s831nwej/

It *almost* works. The problem is that the character counter below the input box is always 1 character less than the total number of characters in the input field. I think there is some quark about the `keypress` event that I am missing.

Comment: `<input type="number" ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the count within [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event or html5 [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/input) event handler.

**HTML :**

```
 <input type="text" id="test" 
     oninput="calculate(this)"
     onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>

<p id='demo'></p>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
// function for preventing certain characters
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// function for calculating the length where element
// reference passed as an argument
function calculate(ele) {
  let inputLength = ele.value.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputLength;
}
```

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function calculate(ele) {
  let inputLength = ele.value.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputLength;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" oninput="calculate(this)" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
<p id='demo'></p>
```

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function calculate(ele) {
  let inputLength = ele.value.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputLength;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" onkeyup="calculate(this)" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
<p id='demo'></p>
```

---

There is a better way using a number input type in html5 which only accept the [number input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

**HTML :**

```
 <input type="number" id="test" 
      oninput="calculate(this)"/>

<p id='demo'></p>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
// function for calculating the length where element
// reference passed as an argument
function calculate(ele) {
  let inputLength = ele.value.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputLength;
}
```

```js
function calculate(ele) {
  let inputLength = ele.value.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputLength;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="test" oninput="calculate(this)" />

<p id='demo'></p>
```

Comment: depending on key being pressed is a bad idea I think. oninput or onchange are better options

Comment: you can copy and paste nonnumbers into your fields

Comment: @JapanGuy `onchange` won't trigger until you leave the field.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer why your keypress creates this unexpected behavior. First of all, it is not related to javascript, it's the feature of your Operating System which interprets your keystrokes and displays them on screen. So, there is nothing you can do with javascript. So, How it works?
When you press a key

> > WM_KEYDOWN and WM_SYSKEYDOWN
>
> messages are sent(condition: the key is not hold) and
>
> > key-state flag is set to zero.

But if condition is you press and hold the key, the flag:

> key-state flag set to 1.

So from there until

> WM_KEYUP or WM_SYSKEYUP

message is not set or key-state flag is set to 1 the data is not stored in input box value. However, it display them inside input box. That's why your keypress do not count the current input value. if you would use

```
keyup event
```

then it would be able to count the current input value also because your OS has done its

> WM_KEYUP

work. for more details how your keyboard works you may refer to this link:
[About Keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx)

and for your next question "number input" you may use regular expression check using and do something like this:

```
var regEx = /^\d+$/;
//then do some check.
if(!regEx.test(document.getElementById("test"))) return false;
```

or you may inside your html input tag

```
<input type="number" .. >
<!-- else you may -->
<input type="text" ... pattern = "\d">;
```

Notic: you also need to check for null values.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly if you want inputs to be only numbers use type="number" instead of type "text" and the count is always less than one because your event handling for checking the value should be on onKeyUp instead of onKeyPress

check this snippet

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('test').value;
  let inputLength = inputValue.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputLength;
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="test" onkeyup="return isNumber(event)" />
<p id='demo'></p>
```

Comment: copy any text paste it with right click. doesnt work